# What is the significane of 8 in Anime and Manga?

Tags: japanese-language, culture, manga-history

I have recently noticed 8 is a pretty common number in the manga I have been reading. Like Samurai 8 and Kaiju NO.8 have the number in their title. There are also 8 gyms in pokemon. Like the number 8 seems very important. Is it related to how the number 4 in Japanese sounds like death?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all comes down to superstition.

4 and 9 are considered "unlucky" numbers because of their phonological resemblance to the words 死 (*shi* – death) and 苦 (*ku* – suffering).

7 and 8, however, are considered luckier. 7's luckiness is steeped in Buddhist tradition and folklore. 8, which is written as 八 in kanji, is reminiscent of a strong foundational base, like a mighty *sugi* or *ginkgo* tree or a firm architectural feat.